# How to parse expressions in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, expression

I want to parse expressions such as res = ((a*(2+b))/c)+5.603+(6*(d^5)). I want to do it in c++ only.

Comment: You might want to look into Boost's Spirit library.

Comment: Or boost regex lib. Or you need to do it without any 3rd party libs?

Comment: I have never used boost, but thanks for reply.

Comment: Can anyone name some third party libs except boost

Comment: I dont understand why when you've been given a solution, i.e. Boost, you reject it and ask for an alternative - what is stopping you from using Boost ?

Comment: If you want to do this old school, use Lex and Yacc (Flex and Bison).

Comment: @Kiril, you can't parse such expressions with regex. Regex doesn't allow for recursive definitions.

Comment: may be I am scared of boost as I have not used it earlier. Once I tried to use boost on windows with mingw and I just messed up things.

Comment: It's certainly true that you don't need boost to parse this. If you don't feel comfortable with boost then don't use it for this; but when you're feeling a bit adventurous, check boost out again. It has so many nice and useful features, it's worth keeping an option.

Comment: There is a ready expression parser in AXE (http://tinyurl.com/3o4hka7), but you need a C++0x compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the ["Available C++ Libraries" FAQ](http://www.trumphurst.com/cpplibs/)

Comment: I should declare an interest - I maintain this FAQ, have done for years.

Answer (score 1):

Stroustrup explains how you'd evaluate expressions like `((1*(2+3))/4)+5.603+(6*(11^5))`. Basically, you build an evaluation tree for all subexpressions.

Your example has three extra steps. In parsing, you have to note the variables `a`, and in evaluating you have to replace the variables with their current values. Finally, you need to assign the result to variables.

You can use a `std::map<std::string, double>` to hold the variable names and values.

Comment: an algorithm would be much appreciated

Comment: Algorithm for what?  The algorithm how to parse (interpret) an expression like `45+12*7` is basic math; each kid learns how to parse that. Evaluating it is also elementary. Parsing `a+12*7` is not that much harder, and evaluating it with `a=45` is also straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thorough treatment of a possible approach to here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-w3eval/index.html

The code is in java, but is quite portable to C++.